# dataloader - how to assign recordtypes

Tags: data-loader

In my SF db I have 3 different Account recordtypes, and I want to import the data for 1 specific record type now. I have mapped all my fields, but cannot find the record type field in the mappings? What is the best way to do this?
Tia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Accounts-->Record Types--> YOUR RECORD TYPE and get the ID from the URL.
 Then, add a column in the import CSV file with this recordtype ID. Name the column as "RecordTypeID". Automap the fields. If that doesn't work, check the recordtypeID field and drop it over the column name. As shown below.
[image]